# facebook sdk logout issue for ios

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook sdk for ios for the first time. I have been facing a weird problem. The 
facebook sdk lets me logout but wont let me login with a different user. do you guys have any idea how to solve this.

I am pasting something that i have used for logout..

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
  // If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
  if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
      || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
    // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically


      NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
      NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
      for (cookie in [storage cookies])
      {
          NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
          NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
          if(domainRange.length > 0)
          {
              [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
          }
      }






    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

  // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
  } else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
             } else {

                 NSLog(@"user dictionary %@",user);
                 // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                 NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                 NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);
                 NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);
                 NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);
                 NSLog(@"FB user username:%@",user.username);
                 NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
                 NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                 NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                                        user.location[@"name"]]);

             }
         }];

       // Retrieve the app delegate
       AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
       // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
       [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
  }
}
```

I am getting a text "You have already authorized Myappname" logging in for the second time after logout. But i am not getting the option for other users to get logged in.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no session like in Websites in ios so you have to log out from Facebook account from safari and than you can again login. as i understand from your question i answered.